# dotnet ef not works with ef tools 1.1.0-preview4-final

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core in dotnet core app. In my `project.json` i have next configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0",
    "AutotestConsolidationServer.Database": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "include": "all"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "include": "all"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.1.0",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.6": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.16.10-x64": {}
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings*.json",
      "databaseconfig*.json",
      "web.config",
      "run.sh"
    ]
  }
}
```

but after publish in output folder there is no any files named ef.dll and off course command `dotnet ef` returns `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`. where is my mistake?

**update**: after @kloarubeek's hint `dotnet-ef.dll` appears in publish out dir, but command `dotnet ef` still not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to it in the *tools* section. If you want to publish it, move it to the *dependencies*:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    }
}
```

Publishing this will result in a dotnet-ef.dll in the output folder.

Comment: but what for _tools_ section then? Also, you right, after moving this line to dependencies appears in publish output, but cmd command `dotnet ef` still not working. Do you have idea why?

Comment: I think the idea was to have a difference between tooling during development (tools) and tooling (and other stuff) that the application depends on (dependencies).

Comment: I only checked whether it was in the output folder. I didn't execute it, it also doesn't run on my side. If I read around you can only run it from the folder that also contains the project.json.

Comment: yes, its working from root project dir, but not from publish output.  Also i said `dotnet-ef.dll` appears in publish output dir.